# Android weakReference to Activity goes null while activity is executing

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am getting a NullPointerException that I cannot understand why this is happening. *mainActivityWeakReference.get() appears to return null.*

So my guess is the Activity is recreated and the reference variable is 
set to null once the class is loaded and the reference is only updated once the onCreate method is called. But what I do not understand is that I am busy performing instructions within the activity that the reference points to
and yet the reference is null.

Can Activities co-exist for a brief moment and how do I handle this situation.
To me it seems that a simple null check would not be sufficient to
address the problem. Perhaps I should call finish();

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity {

  private WeakReference<AppCompatActivity> mainActivityWeakReference = null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         mainActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<AppCompatActivity>(this);
  }

   public void handleAction(UserAction userAction) {
        switch (userAction) {
           case UPDATE_UI:
                << ERROR HERE
                mainActivityWeakReference.get().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                break;
       }
    }
```

My Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.a.m.a' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1476)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
    at za.co.entersekt.nedbank.MainActivity.handleAction(MainActivity.java:297)
```

**More detail added:**

```
public abstract class FragmentManager {
....

public boolean execPendingActions() {
        if (mExecutingActions) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions");
        }

        if (Looper.myLooper() != mActivity.mHandler.getLooper()) {<<FragmentManager.java:1476
            throw new IllegalStateException("Must be called from main thread of process");
        }
```

Comment: Is all this code inside an Activity? Why are you holding a weak reference to `this`? Is calling `this.getSupportFragmentManager()` too easy?

Comment: Also *mainActivityWeakReference.get() appears to return null.* and *<< ERROR HERE* is not true ... it is deeper ... prolly because Activity is in wrong state ...

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#L1588 ... mHost is null - as i wrote before because Activity is in some unusable state

Comment: I have added more detail: the decompiled code for (FragmentManager.java:1476)

Comment: Could it be that I am executing this not on the main thread: mainActivityWeakReference.get().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();


Any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3):

That is because by definition `a weak reference is a reference that does not protect the referenced object from collection by a garbage collecton`
So if you need an instance of activity try doing `getActivity()` or `getContext()`

Comment: Why I am getting a NullPointer exception? Surely the Activity is not garbage collected while I am executing statements.

Comment: yes the activity is not null as the screen is there but the weak reference might be garbage collected. try using getActivity() and check if it works

Comment: I actually think more and more Selvin's comment is more correct.
The actual NullPointerException is within the FragmentManager at line 1476:

Comment: might be true since i had never tried it as it's not a real world scenario i hope it worked with getActivity

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to get the activity, via a hook method:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements....
//....

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>((AppCompatActivity) activity);
}
```

And yes the activity can get re-created for several reasons, at that point
the weak reference turns null, and does not hold a strong reference and therefor eligible for garbage collection.

If it were to hold a strong reference the whole activity would not be eligible for garbage collection, a serious memory leak, holding onto memory longer that what it should.

Activities gan get re-created for several reasons, some of them being:
orientation change, language changes and even when android decides to do this because of some memory constraint.